# javascript confirm message box in usercontrol

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a usercontrol in which i have placed a javascript function which shows the confirm message box. That usercontrol is further called on aspx page.

the function i wrote is :

```
<script>    function CreatePopup() {
    return confirm("Do you confirm?");
}
</script>
```

and then i called the function on the button :

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnAuthenticate" runat="server" Text="Authenticate" 
          OnClientClick="return CreatePopup();"
          OnClick="btnAuthenticate_Click" />
```

What happens is this code is not working.. is there any problem with my function here or do we have certain limitations to look after when adding any scripts in usercontrol? 
This is blowing me off as this was supposed to be the most simpliest task i thought to be!!!

Comment: Try updating it to `<script type='text/javascript'>`

Comment: where you have written javascript function ? in usercontrol or some other page ?

Comment: Is it possible that you have another function called `CreatePopup()` somewhere on the rendered page (or linked static script) that might be overriding it?  Try looking in your F12 development tools for all instances of `CreatePopup`

Comment: I just created the entire scenario and it works. I knew it will, but I had to be sure. From the code you provided there is no error, it should work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I Use Javascript with a page method

```
<script>
function Delete(id) {
            if (confirm("Delete Record?")) 
            {
                PageMethods.DeleteSomething(id, onsuccessDel, onfailDel);
            }
        }

        function onsuccessDel(msg) { window.alert('Did IT!'); }
        function onfailDel(err) {window.alert('Some Error Occured!'); }
</script>
```

And then the HTML or ASPX should have :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptMgr" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnablePageMethods="true" />

 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Delete(1)" title="Delete">Delete</a>
```

The Server side code :

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static void DeleteSomething(int id)
        {
          try{
                 //some code c#
             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw new Exception(ex.toString());
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the working demo there: [Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick).

And the code from here: [code](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick.asp).

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: @freefaller but here is working demo also and have the code that is in working state. well I agree with you. but here is correct answer.

Comment: I understand, but the small pockets of correct information are the problem - they make it look like the entire site can be trusted

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me to display a alert box from user control (ascx).

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('I am from the Server');", true);
```